# How to show a dynamic Tooltip for each value in a MultiSelect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, tooltip, mantine

i want to show tool-tip for each values selected in MultiSelect component. bt i cant find solution for it.

for example, in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnoiO.png) if i hover over react, it shows "react" in tool-tip, if hover over vue, it show "vue" in tool-tip. right now, its not showing any tooltip after select values.

But it only shows when there is no value selected.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNBcP.png)

this is my code.

```
import { MultiSelect } from "@mantine/core";

function New() {
  const [multiSelectVal, setMultiSelectVal] = useState([]);

  const data = [
    { value: "React", label: "React" },
    { value: "Angular", label: "Angular" },
    { value: "Vue", label: "Vue" },
    { value: "NextJS", label: "NextJS" },
  ];

  const handleMultiselect = (e) => {
    setMultiSelectVal(e);
  };

  const events = {
    hover: true,
  };

  const tooltip = (value) => {
    return `This is the tooltip for ${value}`;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MultiSelect
        data={data}
        events={events}
        title={tooltip(multiSelectVal)}
        onChange={(e) => handleMultiselect(e)}
        value={multiSelectVal}
        label="Frameworks"
        placeholder="Pick all that you like"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default New;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mantine's MultiSelect component doesn't have an `events` prop, the [proper way to customise the display of an item is to create an item component and pass it via the `itemComponent` prop](https://mantine.dev/core/multi-select/#custom-item-component).

For example:

```
import { useState, forwardRef } from "react";
import { Tooltip, Text, MantineProvider, MultiSelect } from "@mantine/core";

const SelectItem = forwardRef(({ value, ...others }, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} {...others}>
    <Tooltip label={`This is the tooltip for ${value}`}>
      <Text>{value}</Text>
    </Tooltip>
  </div>
));

function Test() {
  const [multiSelectVal, setMultiSelectVal] = useState([]);

  const data = [
    { value: "React", label: "React" },
    { value: "Angular", label: "Angular" },
    { value: "Vue", label: "Vue" },
    { value: "NextJS", label: "NextJS" }
  ];

  const handleMultiselect = (e) => {
    setMultiSelectVal(e);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MultiSelect
        data={data}
        onChange={(e) => handleMultiselect(e)}
        value={multiSelectVal}
        itemComponent={SelectItem}
        label="Frameworks"
        placeholder="Pick all that you like"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[Here's a link to the Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-shockley-xl8z6d)

Comment: Thank for trying. But i think you misunderstood my problem. i don't want to show tooltip in dropdown component. i want to show it at tags which appear in input after select any value.